# How to install parsecsv: explicit steps sought

Tags: centos, software-installation, php

From https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php#installation:

> Installation is easy using Composer. Just run the following on the
>   command line:
>
> composer require parsecsv/php-parsecsv
>
> If you don't use a framework such as Drupal, Laravel, Symfony, Yii
>   etc., you may have to manually include Composer's autoloader file in
>   your PHP script:
>
> require_once **DIR** . '/vendor/autoload.php';
>
> Without composer
>
> Not recommended, but technically possible: you can also clone the
>   repository or extract the ZIP. To use ParseCSV, you then have to add a
>   require 'parsecsv.lib.php'; line.

1. I'm rather novice at Linux and I have no idea what Composer is?  What are the explicit steps to install `parsecsv`?
2. Which files do I need to download, if any?
3. Where do I place the files?
4. Does the method described automatically install the program to the standard bin path, whatever that is?

I am using Centos 7.

`[root@server test]# yum install composer`: yields some errors:

```
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-cli
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-openssl
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-iconv
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-composer(composer/spdx-licenses) >= 1.2
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-reflection
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-json
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-justinrainbow-json-schema5
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-symfony-process
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-pcre
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-curl
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-composer(seld/jsonlint) < 2
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-filter
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-composer(fedora/autoloader)
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-hash
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-symfony-console
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-composer(composer/semver) < 2
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-composer(psr/log) < 2
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-phar
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-libxml
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-zip
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-PsrLog >= 1.0.0-8
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-composer(composer/xdebug-handler) < 2
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-composer(composer/ca-bundle) >= 1.0
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-date
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-spl
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-seld-phar-utils >= 1.0.1
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-dom
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-mbstring
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php(language) >= 5.3.2
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-xsl
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-zlib
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-composer(seld/jsonlint) >= 1.4
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-composer(composer/xdebug-handler) >= 1.1
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-simplexml
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-composer(psr/log) >= 1.0
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-composer(seld/phar-utils) >= 1.0
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-composer(composer/spdx-licenses) < 2
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-composer(seld/phar-utils) < 2
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-composer(composer/ca-bundle) < 2
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-symfony-finder
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-symfony-filesystem
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-tokenizer
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-composer(composer/semver) >= 1.0
Error: Package: composer-1.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-intl
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `composer require parsecsv/php-parsecsv` as mentioned. If you don't have composer, CentOS has it as a package: `yum install composer`

Comment: I don't know how to resolve the numerous dependencies.  Is there no way to automatically resolve them? (see original post for latest)